# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. even if I am using compose in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get some data from api call in redux:

```
import {createStore,combineReducers,compose,applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import math from "./reducers/mathReducer"
import user from "./reducers/userReducer"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
                user,math
            }),
        {},
        compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
        );
export default store;
```

The fetch data code is:

```
export function setName()
{
    fetch('http://localhost/login.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then( (response) => {
        return {
            type:'SET_NAME',
            payload: response.name
        };
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
        console.warn('Actions - fetchJobs - recreived error: ', error)
    })


}
```

I am getting issue:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if `applyMiddleware` is the only enhancer you are using you don't need `compose`. Also no need empty object as an initial state. Just `createStore( combineReducers({ user,math }), applyMiddleware(thunk));` will be enough

Comment: Something like this: `const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    user,math
   }),
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );` But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing actions to use dispatch solved the above issue:

```
export function setName(name)
{
    console.log("Inside setName.");
    return dispatch =>
    {
        fetch('http://localhost/login.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then( (response) => {
            dispatch({
                type:'SET_NAME',
                payload: response.name
            });

        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.warn('Actions - fetchJobs - recreived error: ', error)
        })

    }   
}
```